# jQuery get id of closest li

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="sortable">

  <li class="ui-state-default editor-sortable-moveable" id="123">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid"></div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid">Text</div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid icon-flow"><i class="fas fa-edit" id="editor_click_icon_edit"></i></div>
  </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

When clicking the icon, i need to get the id of the parent `<li>`.

I'm using the following click listener:

```
$("#sortable").click("#editor_click_icon_edit",function(e) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

This will return "Text".

By using

```
$(this).children().attr('id');
```

I just returns the id of the first `<li>` entry. So it looks like "this" points to the `<ul>`.

Comment: You want `$("#sortable").on("click", "#editor_click_icon_edit",function(e) { ... })` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: So in your title you say "closest li" So use the closest method!

Comment: Also hope you realize that ids are singular. Seems like an edit button repeats so you will not be able to use an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly you're not using `click()` correctly. The first argument in your case is the additional data you want to include in the event, but that's not relevant to your use case. Instead it appears you're trying to create a delegated event handler, but you need to use `on()` for that.

Secondly, you need to traverse the DOM to find the parent `li` from the clicked element. `closest()` will achieve this for you.

```js
$("#sortable").on('click', "#editor_click_icon_edit", function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest('li').prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default editor-sortable-moveable" id="123">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid"></div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid">Text</div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid icon-flow">
        <i class="fas fa-edit" id="editor_click_icon_edit"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Title states "closest li"

Comment: The click listener was the problem. Got it working with the following code.   $("#sortable").on('click', "#editor_click_icon_edit", function(e) {
      console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('id'))
    }); Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd strongly suggest you use `closest()` instead of chaining multiple `parent()` calls. For one the former will work if the DOM changes slightly. The latter won't, and frankly, it's just ugly.

Answer (score 0):

fyi, if you use a snippet its easier for us to run and see whats up. 
Below in the snippet i switched it from adding the listener to the ul. now it adds the listener to the lis nested inside your ul.

```js
//#sortable is the id of the ul
//.editor-sortable-movable grabs the li
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sortable > li").on("click",function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```css
.editor-sortable-moveable {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.editor-sortable-moveable:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">

  <li class="ui-state-default editor-sortable-moveable" id="123">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid"></div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid">Text</div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid icon-flow"><i class="fas fa-edit" id="editor_click_icon_edit"></i></div>
  </div>
  </li>
<li class="ui-state-default editor-sortable-moveable" id="456">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid"></div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid">Next</div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill li-content-grid icon-flow"><i class="fas fa-edit" id="editor_click_icon_edit"></i></div>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why the down vote? please provide context so the answer can be amended.